# Update in one to one relation table laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables that are in one to one relationship:

tours :

`id|title|content`

featured_image:

`id|tour_id|name|path`

My models FeaturedImage.php:

```
class FeaturedImage extends Model
{
protected $fillables = [
    'name',
    'path',
    'tour_id',
];

public function tour()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour');
 }
}
```

Tours.php

```
class Tour extends Model
{
protected $fillables = [
    'title',
    'content',
];

public function featuredImage()
 {
  return $this->hasOne('App\FeaturedImage');
 }
}
```

I'm trying to update the `featured_image` table when new image for tour is uploaded:

1. update `path` column in `featured_image` table with new file's path
2. Delete the old image

Below is my method for updating `featured_image`'s path column:

```
// update featured image       
    if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
    $featured_image= new FeaturedImage;
// add the new photo
    $image = $request->file('featured_image');
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $location = 'images/featured_image/'.$filename; 
    //dd($location);
    Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

    $oldFilename= $tour->featuredImage->path;
// update the database
    $featured_image->path = $location;
// Delete the old photo
    File::delete(public_path($oldFilename));
    }
```

The above code sucessfully deletes the old image and uploads the new, but it fails to update the path column. I ran `dd($location);`, it gives the path of the new image but doesn;t save in the db column.

Comment: `$featured_image->save()` after you assign the new location to the `path` property.
`$featured_image->path = $location; $featured_image->save();`

Comment: I dit that and got error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tour_id' doesn't have a default value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save relation like this:

```
$featuredImage = $tour->featuredImage;
$featuredImage->path = $location;
$tour->featuredImage()->save($featuredImage);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

Comment: if $tour->featuredImage is empty you can create new featuredImage before updating. Like this: $featuredImage = $tour->featuredImage ? $tour->featuredImage : new featuredImage;